# How do I remove Typscript namespaces

Tags: typescript

I want to refactor a file that has two namespaces in it with functions that have the same name. In that sense, I cannot just remove the namespace.

```
//myFile.ts
export namespace Square{
    export function drawMe() {
        console.info("drawing a square")
    }
    export function ColorMe() {
        console.info("coloring a square")
    }
}

export namespace Circle {
    export function drawMe() {
        console.info("drawing a circle")
    }
    export function ColorMe() {
        console.info("coloring a circle")
    }
}


//aDifferentFile.ts
import {Square} from "shapes";
import {Circle} from "shapes";

Square.ColorMe();
Circle.drawMe();
```

If I replace the namespaces and export as ES6 Module as a const, then it would look like this :

```
//myFile.ts
export const Square = {
    drawMe : function() {
        console.info("drawing a square")
    },

    ColorMe : function () {
        console.info("coloring a square")
    }
}

export const Circle = {
    drawMe: function() {
        console.info("drawing a circle")
    },
    ColorMe: function() {
        console.info("coloring a circle")
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do get rid of namespaces? It seems that I would have to do a lot of rewriting in this case. However I would like to keep refactoring to a minimum.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the namespaces? Namespaces exist in order to allow you to have functions with the same name that don't pollute the global namespace. TS namespaces compile to JS objects anyway, so your object refactoring only interferes with typing.

Comment: Namespaces are deprecated and can be replaced by ES6 modules. In any case I am trying to use Storybook.js for my project, but it will not work with namespaces.

Comment: If you can split to files - you can have a module per namespace (just remove `export namespace Foo` wrapper) and then on consumer side: `import * as Square from "./square";`